# Results of not using '{}' in find /mnt/tmp -atime +91 -exec rm -f {} \;?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, find, exec

I have been using the following code for the longest on a system I took over:

```
find /mnt/tmp -atime +91 -exec rm -f {} \;
```

However, researching further I see everyone saying the curly braces should be enclosed in single quotes like below:

```
find /mnt/tmp -atime +91 -exec rm -f '{}' \;
```

I have never had issues before, but I am curious of any negative impact not using the single quotes might have. Also curious if it varies across linux flavors?

The servers are Ubuntu.

Comment: you may want to add '-type f' so it won't complain it can't "rm" a directory? : `find /mnt/tmp -type f -atime +91 -exec rm -f '{}' \;`

Comment: A simpler version is: `find /mnt/tmp -atime +91 -delete` - or use tmpwatch/tmpreaper :)

Comment: @DennisKaarsemaker, is there any difference in functionality between rm -f and -delete in the way I am trying to use it? @ Oliver, thanks for the input :)

Comment: Yes, `-exec rm -f` forks and exec's one rm per file. `-delete` makes find simply unlink the file, that's a *lot* faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The impacts you're speaking of will show up if you have "special" characters in your filenames (as distinct from regex-type special characters). The most obvious would be if you have a file named `foo /*` - your rm command would go and remove `foo` then `/*` without the single quotes, which you probably wouldn't want.

Comment: Ahh thanks. Yes currently the files are all alphanumeric with no spaces or special characters, which would explain why I haven't ran into any issues. Thank you.